# Thunderbird Compose window opening somewhere OTHER than top left corner?

Tags: thunderbird, window

I'd like to open my Thunderbird compose email window somewhere other than the upper right hand corner. Here's the command I'm using:

`/usr/bin/thunderbird -compose`

I tried using the geometry command, with no luck. Any ideas? Thunderbird *does* remember the *size* of the window, but not the location that it opens in.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else comes up, you can use wmctrl and move the window after it opens.. Something like:

this will move and resize the active compose window

/usr/bin/thunderbird -compose; wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,100,100,600,400

Or you can even configure a devilspie rule to do this automagically:
http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie/

Answer (score 0):

Try Compiz's window management settings under `Window Management > Place Windows` -- you can define a rule that only applies to Thunderbird compose windows.